# How to I open a menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, metro-ui-css

I have just started using Metro UI CSS and I'm rather impressed by its look and feel.  I am however having some issues controlling my UI.

I am trying to have a menu open on initialization of the page but I cant figure out how to do it and the documentation is quite limited in terms of controlling inputs.  Below is a standard example taken from the documentation.  All I am trying to do is have the products menu open on startup....

my example below does not render correctly but I don't think it needs to for such a simple thing.

`example` https://jsfiddle.net/robeastham/p20ykv7q/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did a codePen for your menu.

You can look here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqopzv

```
<div class="app-bar">
        <a class="app-bar-element" href="...">Home</a>
        <span class="app-bar-divider"></span>
        <ul class="app-bar-menu">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Products</a>
                <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="">Windows 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Spartan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Outlook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Office 2015</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Other Products</a>
                        <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="">Internet Explorer 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Skype</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Surface</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Don't forget, look external source CSS and JS in codePen.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for looking Greg,  I can see you have added the required resources to render the CSS, which is great,  however my original question remains: How do I programatically open the 'Products' menu?

Thanks for taking time to look though ;)

Comment: Thanks Greg  - great help!